# Graphical Root User in Ubuntu Focal Fossa- Drivers not working

Tags: drivers, 20.04, gui, root

***Sound and USB ports not working on Ubuntu (focal fossa) root GUI user account.***

I recently noticed that the already insufficient free space remaining on the */home* partition of my Ubuntu *20.04(Focal Fossa)* OS *(Installed as a dual boot alongside Windows 10)* is filling up rapidly. And every time the remaining free space on that partition was reduced to less than 1GB as I am using it, the computer freezes, meanwhile the */root* partition remained with plenty of free space.
I believe I was mislead by the tutorial when I was installing Ubuntu as a dual boot and did not leave enough HDD space for the */home* partition and left plenty for the */root* partition. Perhaps, far more than necessary...

As a result, I wanted to install all my future downloaded software on the root partition - one of which was meant to be wine-. I did that in order to solve the problem of the computer freezing while I'm doing random work such as using multiple web browser tabs or more than one application simultaneously.

I found an article which explained how to access root not just from Terminal but also as a GUI. *(Before you say anything, I am already aware that this is a very risky path to take.)* I created the root GUI user profile.

After installing Wine on the graphical */root* user profile interface, I noticed that the speakers were not working, and neither were the USB ports.
I managed to install *.exe* packages without any issues and used them but with no sound, and I cannot use any USB drives to export/import data either.

**If anyone is familiar with using root as a graphical user interface, please let me know how I can fix this issue.**

Comment: The root `/` partition is different to the `/root` directory (which can also be it's own partition).  You mention "/root" which is different to "/" (root) so please clarify.  A GUI user interface should **not** be run as a root user for security reasons.  As for disk partitions filling, you've not provided any details on space you allocated (more or less than the 25GB minimum recommended etc)

Comment: Hi @guiverc
Thank you for the prompt response.
I meant the root partition and the home partition. As in the filesystem partitions mounted at /home and the one mounted at Filesystem Root. They are 10GB for the /home partition and 40GB for the Root.

Ps. I have also re worded my initial post, hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: You still mention "*meanwhile the /root partition remained*"  which would be expected.  Almost no data gets written to /root, as it's a different directory to the / (or root) directory.  Only some config files ever get written to /root (which are usually tiny, measured in bytes or KB)

Comment: @guiverc 
You are right.
That's what I noticed. I did not know this before. 

And it is also why I realized I should have left more extra space for the home partition instead of the /root. 
I wanted to take advantage of the extra space I had left on the /root partition. Which is why I used it as a GUI.

Any ideas how I can fix this? ( Meaning the driver problems...)